# Spring Boot: External Properties File not loading

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that will have to have some properties set by the end user.  To accomplish this, I'm using an external application.properties file.  Unfortunately, no matter what I try, these properties never seem to get loaded.  As of now, I've tried the following in Powershell.

```
java -Dspring.config.location=file:./application-dev.properties 
-jar gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar 

java -jar gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar 
--spring.config.location=file:./C:\Users\someone\Desktop\PropertiesTest\application.properties
```

As a canary, I have spring.main.banner-mode=off, and no matter what I try, I see the banner getting shown in the console.

Does anyone know how to persuade Spring or Java to look at a file I've set for properties?  I'm trying to avoid using an OS variable because that seems overkill and brittle.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I'm a dodo bird.  The correct solution was to remove the dot in the "file./C:.." string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my .jar file was created by my *jar* Gradle script which created a jar file.  This jar file was only ~60MB in size.  Once I used the output of my Gradle *build* script, the jar was about ~120MB and everything worked as expected